# How do I get this amount in the output in sql developer?

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Re8HZ.png)

The amount for the cost doesn't match up.

I tried
select 'Average order total $' || avg(sum(quantityordered*priceeach)) as "Customer Report"
from orderdetails od
group by od.priceeach;

and also this

SELECT avg(AVG(od.QUANTITYORDERED * od.PRICEEACH)) AS avg_order_total
FROM ORDERDETAILS od
JOIN ORDERS o ON od.ORDERNUMBER = o.ORDERNUMBER
GROUP BY o.CUSTOMERNUMBER;

customer table:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/W53DI.png

orderdetails table:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/SzB3Y.png

orders table:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/oIlve.png

Comment: Please [edit] to paste the text used in the image into your question so that it can be read on all devices, quoted, edited, and found through search. As it stands now, [your image makes it hard to answer your question or for people with related issues to find your question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). See the [formatting documentation](/editing-help) for tips to make your text appear nicely without resorting to images.

Answer (score 0):

One of the options to get you the expected result could be using three unioned queries like this:

```sql
    Select    'Average order total: ' || Round(Sum(QUANTITY * PRICE) / Count(DISTINCT ORDER_NUMBER), 2) "STATS" 
    From      order_details 
Union All
    Select    'Number of customers with order totals over $32,000.00: ' || CNT 
    From  ( SELECT Count(*) "CNT"
            FROM (Select o.CUSTOMER_NUMBER, Sum(od.QUANTITY * od.PRICE) "CUST_TOTAL" From orders o Inner Join order_details od ON(od.ORDER_NUMBER = o.ORDER_NUMBER) Group By o.CUSTOMER_NUMBER) 
            WHERE CUST_TOTAL > 32000
          )
Union All
    Select    'Number of customers with order totals upto $32,000.00: ' || CNT 
    From  ( SELECT Count(*) "CNT"
            FROM (Select o.CUSTOMER_NUMBER, Sum(od.QUANTITY * od.PRICE) "CUST_TOTAL" From orders o Inner Join order_details od ON(od.ORDER_NUMBER = o.ORDER_NUMBER) Group By o.CUSTOMER_NUMBER) 
            WHERE CUST_TOTAL <= 32000
          )
```

Which with (reduced) sample data as:

```sql
WITH
    customers AS
        (
            Select 1 "CUSTOMER_NUMBER", 'Jack' "CUSTOMER_NAME" From Dual Union All
            Select 2 "CUSTOMER_NUMBER", 'Jane' "CUSTOMER_NAME" From Dual Union All
            Select 3 "CUSTOMER_NUMBER", 'Mick' "CUSTOMER_NAME" From Dual 
        ),
    orders AS
        (
            Select 1 "ORDER_NUMBER", To_Date('01.02.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy') "ORDER_DATE", 1 "CUSTOMER_NUMBER" From Dual Union All
            Select 2 "ORDER_NUMBER", To_Date('03.02.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy') "ORDER_DATE", 1 "CUSTOMER_NUMBER" From Dual Union All
            Select 3 "ORDER_NUMBER", To_Date('09.02.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy') "ORDER_DATE", 1 "CUSTOMER_NUMBER" From Dual Union All
            Select 4 "ORDER_NUMBER", To_Date('11.02.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy') "ORDER_DATE", 2 "CUSTOMER_NUMBER" From Dual Union All
            Select 5 "ORDER_NUMBER", To_Date('12.02.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy') "ORDER_DATE", 2 "CUSTOMER_NUMBER" From Dual Union All
            Select 6 "ORDER_NUMBER", To_Date('15.02.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy') "ORDER_DATE", 3 "CUSTOMER_NUMBER" From Dual 
        ),
    order_details AS
        (
            Select 1 "ORDER_NUMBER",  101 "PRODUCT_NUMBER",  100 "QUANTITY", 250 "PRICE" From Dual Union All
            Select 1 "ORDER_NUMBER",  102 "PRODUCT_NUMBER",  150 "QUANTITY", 120 "PRICE" From Dual Union All
            Select 2 "ORDER_NUMBER",  101 "PRODUCT_NUMBER",  100 "QUANTITY", 250 "PRICE" From Dual Union All
            Select 3 "ORDER_NUMBER",  103 "PRODUCT_NUMBER",  110 "QUANTITY", 100 "PRICE" From Dual Union All
            Select 4 "ORDER_NUMBER",  101 "PRODUCT_NUMBER",   10 "QUANTITY", 250 "PRICE" From Dual Union All
            Select 4 "ORDER_NUMBER",  102 "PRODUCT_NUMBER",   12 "QUANTITY", 120 "PRICE" From Dual Union All
            Select 5 "ORDER_NUMBER",  103 "PRODUCT_NUMBER",   82 "QUANTITY", 100 "PRICE" From Dual Union All
            Select 5 "ORDER_NUMBER",  104 "PRODUCT_NUMBER",   20 "QUANTITY",  25 "PRICE" From Dual Union All
            Select 5 "ORDER_NUMBER",  105 "PRODUCT_NUMBER",  100 "QUANTITY",  18 "PRICE" From Dual Union All
            Select 6 "ORDER_NUMBER",  101 "PRODUCT_NUMBER",   90 "QUANTITY", 250 "PRICE" From Dual Union All
            Select 6 "ORDER_NUMBER",  102 "PRODUCT_NUMBER",  100 "QUANTITY", 120 "PRICE" From Dual 
        )
```

... would result as:

```sql
STATS                                                                                         
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Average order total: 21323.33                                           
Number of customers with order totals over $32,000.00: 2                
Number of customers with order totals upto $32,000.00: 1
```